# Validity of a proposition

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a map such that $|f|$ is measurable and for all finite set $F\subset \mathbb{R}$, set $f^{-1}(F)$ is measurable.

Now, is following sentence a valid proposition?

**If $f$ is one-to-one, then $f$ is measurable.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that does not imply the measurability of $f$. If $f$ is one-to-one (injective), then $f^{-1}(F)$ is finite, and hence measurable for all finite $F\subset\mathbb{R}$, regardless of whether $f$ is measurable or not.

To find a counterexample, let $N \subset (0,\infty)$ a non-measurable set, and define

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x &, x \in N \lor -x\in N\\ -x &, \text{ otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

Then $f^{-1}((0,\infty)) = N \cup \bigl((-\infty,0) \setminus (-N)\bigr)$ is not measurable, whence the non-measurability of $f$, but $\lvert f(x)\rvert = \lvert x\rvert$ is measurable.